# Handle Stripe errors in the model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, stripe-payments

Is it possible to render Stripe error messages as notices when using a method within the model. This is my controller at the moment

```
def create
  @donation = @campaign.donations.create(donation_params)
    if @donation.save_with_payment
      redirect_to @campaign, notice: 'Card charged successfully.'
    else
      render :new
    end
end
```

and my method is like so

```
def save_with_payment
  customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
    :email => email,
    :card  => stripe_token
  )

  charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
    :customer    => customer.id,
    :amount      => donation_amount,
    :description => 'Rails Stripe customer',
    :currency    => 'usd'
 )
end
```

I have noticed from other peoples examples that Stripe has a

```
rescue Stripe::error
 rescue Stripe::InvalidRequestError => e
```

But I'm not sure how to grab these errors and then put them within a notice.

Comment: How do you want to deal with it?  Do you want `save_with_payment` to mean it fails validation? Also, you have an instance method not a class method.

Comment: sorry got mixed up with my methods there, thanks for clarifying. I would like to handle the errors within save_with_payment and show the error to the user, via a notice if possible

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this, assuming save_with_payment is a callback (before_create or before_save I'd assume)

```
def save_with_payment
  customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
    :email => email,
    :card  => stripe_token
  )

  charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
    :customer    => customer.id,
    :amount      => donation_amount,
    :description => 'Rails Stripe customer',
    :currency    => 'usd'
 )
rescue Stripe::error => e
   errors[:base] << "This donation is invalid because #{e}"
rescue Stripe::InvalidRequestError => e
   errors[:base] << "This donation is invalid because #{e}"
end
```

You might want to see if stripe has more specific errors it creates though, if so you can add the error onto a specific attribute the donation has.  For example (making up an invalid email error and because a donation has an email by the looks of it)

```
rescue Stripe::InvalidEmailError => e
  errors.add(:email, e)
end
```

Comment: Also you might want to split save with payment to call two other methods, one for customer and one for charge so you can rescue customer related errors in one and charge related in the other